# EloquentJavascript Ch.6 "Another Cell" section wierd behavior in constructor

Tags: javascript

I was working on Eloquent Javascript chapter 6 exercise "Another Cell" and found something weird. Please look at the following code for the constructor I wrote. StretchCell inherits from UnderlinedCell also displayed below.

UnderlinedCell

```
function UnderlinedCell(inner) {
  this.inner = inner;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minWidth = function() {
  return this.inner.minWidth();
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minHeight = function() {
  return this.inner.minHeight() + 1;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.draw = function(width, height) {
  return this.inner.draw(width, height - 1)
    .concat([repeat("-", width)]);
};
```

StretchCell constructor Version 1

```
function StretchCell(inner, minWidth, minHeight){
  this.inner = inner;
  if (minWidth > inner.minWidth)
    this.inner.minWidth = minWidth;
  if (minHeight > inner.minHeight)
    this.inner.minHeight = minHeight;
};
```

StretchCell constructor Version 2

```
function StretchCell(inner, minWidth, minHeight){
  this.inner = inner;
  this.inner.minWidth = Math.max(inner.minWidth, minWidth);
  this.inner.minHeight = Math.max(inner.minWidth, minHeight);
};
```

Both versions of code seems okay to me since both are directly modifying the variable, and both are assigning it a value, but I'm getting error from Version 2 when running in the sandbox provided on eloquentjavascript website. It's pretty weird. Is there something that I'm missing here?

EDIT:
Error I'm receiving-

```
TypeError: this.inner.minWidth is not a function (line 97 in function UnderlinedCell.minWidth) 
 called from line 12
```

Comment: Doesn't help if you don't say what the error is.

Comment: @Andy Okay, I added the error message.

Comment: How are you calling `StretchCell`? I can only guess it assigns NaN to minWidth.

Comment: Shouldn't you have made a call to `this.inner.minWidth` in both versions. It looks like a function.

Comment: @user152807 The call is handled already in the exercise "Another Cell" [ch6](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html), which is called by `var sc = new StretchCell(new TextCell("abc"), 1, 2);` followed by `console.log(sc.minWidth());` I've posted my implements of StretchCell in the question. However Version 1 works as intended; Version 2 does not. I did not change any of the default code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.inner.minWidth = Math.max(inner.minWidth, minWidth);
 this.inner.minHeight = Math.max(inner.minWidth, minHeight);
```

After this code, `this.inner.minWidth` and `this.inner.minHeight` both become values returned from `Math.max()`. In this case `this.inner.minWidth` and `this.inner.minHeight` are expected to be functions, so it cannot run!